# Check whether a random sample comes from an elliptical distribution?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, joint-distribution, multivariate-distribution

How can I check whether it is a reasonable assumption to say that a multivariate sample $x_1,...,x_n$ comes from an elliptical distribution, such as a normal distribution or a t-distribution?

In the case of normal or t-distributions, would it be sufficient to compute the squared Mahalanobis-distance of each data point w.r.t. the sample mean $\mu$ and the sample covariance matrix $\Sigma$, 
\begin{align*}
\text{Maha}(x_i)=(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu),\quad i=1,...,n,
\end{align*}
and look at whether its empirical distribution resembles a chi-squared distribution or an F-distribution, respectively? If so, could a similar approach be used in general for elliptical distributions?

Comment: normal and t are not the only elliptical distributions, so it's "e.g." rather than "i.e."

Comment: Okay but now in relation to your second paragraph, it should be clear to you that checking for normal or t is not the same as checking for an elliptical distribution. Are you interested in elliptical distributions or just t-distributions (including the normal as a limiting case)?

Comment: This was supposed to serve as a motivating example. Multivariate normal and t distributions would be of primary interest, elliptical distributions in general an added bonus. I have updated the question further.

Comment: I think you're possibly looking in the wrong direction; consider a set of ellipse-shaped curves along which the distribution had cycles within which there were sections of greater and lesser  density as you progressed around the ellipse. Averaged around the ellipse the density might closely match an elliptical distribution so the profile as a function of Mahalanobis' distance might look just fine. In such a case it would be the changing density as you go around the supposed contours that would be where the non-elliptical 'action' is, rather than across them